# Get time out of a dateTime string

Tags: javascript, time, format, compare

I've a dateTime string - '2020-04-30 07:00:00'.
I need to extract the time '07:00:00' and check if it is less than or equal to '11:30' hrs.

How do I do that in easiest way?

Comment: Basically, you need to to the opposite of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304144/comparing-javascript-dates-while-ignoring-time-of-day

Answer (score 0):

Parse your string to a date:

```
const d = new Date(Date.parse('2020-04-30 07:00:00'))
```

Test whatever you want:

```
if (d.getHours() < 11 || (d.getHours() === 11 && d.getMinutes() <= 30)) {
    // earlier than 11:30 or 11:30
}
```